# MaterializeCSS form visible over navbar

Tags: css, html, materialize

So, I'm having fun, testing out MaterializeCSS for my new website. Then I realized.

The visuals of my form are hovering on top of my navbar. And this is an issue that I regrettably can't fix and probably has a simple and obvious fix to it...! But I myself am too blind to see it. Could someone help out?

[Sana Rinomi's Contact Page](https://sanarinomi.com/contact)

EDIT: I know I'm crappy at explaining issues so I'd though maybe some visuals might help.

[image: Text on top of Navbar]

[image: Button on top of Navbar]

Comment: try to remove this code, .pinned {
     position: fixed !important; 
}

Comment: While yes, of course that would stop the issue, it isn't something that I want to do, as I do want my navbar to be pinned to the top of my screen. What I don't want is the text, buttons and decoration from the form overlapping the navbar.

Comment: if you pay attention, you will observe that your social icons and Contact Me are not  being visualized on scroll. there is something wrong with form only

Comment: I know, that's why I stated "form visuals" as it has something to do with the properties of the form itself. That's why I am asking to see if someone knows a fix to this issue as I do enjoy the look of the form with the MaterializeCSS framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, this is quite simple solution. You don't have to remove the fixed position, but you'll have to compensate for the height of the navbar. Position fixed removes the element from the flow, so the other elements "don't see it".

So, basically just add top margin to your Page container and give it a value of navbar's height:

```
.pageContainer {
  margin-top: 64px;
}
```

Note that you have to account for different screen sizes and changes of navbar.

additional reading which may help.

> The (fixed) element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout.
>   [MDN - CSS/position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

**EDIT** (after further conversation and clarification, I am updating the answer):
Original problem happens on scroll. It's because form (or the whole pageContainer) has z-index which is higher than nav (bar). I have added `z-index: 2` to the `nav` element directly in dev tools on Mozilla Firefox and it solved the issue.

Comment: Sorry, that isn't the issue, I have added some images so you can see what the issue is! '^^

Comment: I have opened the page in 3 different browsers and I can't replicate that behaviour. It would really help if you tell which browser you are using and at which resolution. Btw, you should either way compensate for the nav's height. It may not present a problem now, but later it most probably will.

Comment: @AmeliaAldridge ah, now I see what you mean. You should have said it happens on scroll. That's the issue with z-index of the `nav` element. `z-index: 2` worked for me when it's set directly on NAV element. Try it.

Comment: I am currently using Firefox: Developer Edition and a standard 1920x1080 resolution. I have seen this behavior across all devices I've seen with the form open, as I had asked some friends to open it up on their devices (phones, tablets and laptops) and the issue remained.

Comment: We were writing at the same time. Like I said, the confusion occurred because you didn't mention it happens on scroll. Z-index will take care of that :)

Comment: Thank you! Hahahahaha! I'm a very confusing person! Sorry! '^^ That definitely fixed the issue! I know this may be  cheeky of me, but could you edit your awnser above for any other poor soul that has a similar issue? On that note, I must add that compensation for the navbar is done with the `standalone` class which gives compensation using `padding` and `vh` (`vh` because of different screen sizes really). Hahahaha!